# Most efficient technique to build a series of R vignettes, with one for each example data set?

Tags: r, knitr, r-package, vignette

We are building an `r package` to assess income inequality in survey data https://github.com/DjalmaPessoa/convey

I have about ten different public use microdata sets here - https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree - that I would like to provide usage examples with dataset-specific vignettes.  For the most part, the vignettes will be exactly the same, I just want a distinct vignette available for the different surveys.  I only want a handful of things to vary across the vignette, like:
`title/vignette` name, survey load script, survey design object name, income variable within dataset

The package we are writing has about a dozen different functions that I would like to demonstrate in a (seemingly for the user) dataset-specific manner across ten different public use files-- but I don't want to write ten nearly-identical vignettes

Is there a reasonable way to write a single document that will then auto-generate specific vignettes?  I am thinking about something like a Microsoft mail merge, but am not sure what the equivalent would be here.  Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a templating package, like `brew`, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brew/index.html, or similar

Comment: @user101089 that might be right, thank you!